# Actor not remembering state

Tags: scala, akka, jnativehook

I am trying to create a sample application that monitors key strokes from scala on a windows machine using the jNativeHook library.

I have the following listener that listens for events,

```
object KeyListener extends org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener {

  val keyPressedActor = implicitly[ActorSystem].actorOf(Props[KeyPressedActor](), "KeyPressedActor")

  def nativeKeyPressed(event: NativeKeyEvent): Unit = {
    keyPressedActor ! event    
  }
 //blank override two more methods.
}
```

The main driver app that plugs the listener,

```
object ConsoleApp extends App {
  try {
    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(KeyListener)
  } catch {
    case nativehookException: NativeHookException => System.out.println("Encountered error while Hooking to global screen" + nativehookException.fillInStackTrace())
    case ex: Exception                            => System.out.println("Miserable ! Shouldn't have happened ." + ex.fillInStackTrace())
  }
}
```

And this is the implementation of the actor that i want to store the key strokes in some collection,

```
class KeyPressedActor extends Actor {
  var testQueue = new scala.collection.mutable.Queue[String]()

  def receive = {
    case event: NativeKeyEvent =>

      if (event.paramString().contains("modifiers=Ctrl")) {
         testQueue.enqueue("this_is_test")        
      }

    case _ => System.out.println("Bummer !  You are NOT supposed to see THIS !")
  }
}
```

Now i am seeing each time the actor enters the block where we add a string to the queue it does not remember the last element that got inserted into it.

I cannot understand why this is happening.
This problem is not seen if i just have a Main app that sends messages to the actor.
I cannot put a finger on why this is happening.

---

Update :

Actually there is something else going on with the code in a section i did not copy here initially.
So if i have this inside the `if` block of the actor ,

```
NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode) match {
          case "C" =>   
                        isCPressed = true
          case "V" => isVPressed = true
          case "N" => isNPressed = true
```

this behavior is observed.
I changed this code to this ,

```
 val keyCode = NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(event.getKeyCode)

        if (keyCode.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
         testQueue.enqueue("this_is_test")
        }
```

I wonder if this means that the `match` statement is running on some different context/thread ???

Comment: What is your test for checking whether or not it 'remembers the last element that got inserted' ?

Comment: Well i am currently using breakpoint in eclipse. But i have tried using a print over the queue as well. This is the smallest working code that i could do.

Comment: Your `queue` is both mutable and a var. That's confusing.

Comment: That is because var or val should affect the reference while the collection itself being mutable affects the contents.

Comment: In this case the queue can be a val since it isnt being reassigned, unless you are reassigning it outside this code. Anyway I dont see any issue with this. I would verify that only one actor is being created and only one queue is being created

Comment: But if i want to have shared state it has to be a var right ?

Comment: what do you mean by shared state? It would only need to be 'var' if you reassign to the same variable name.

Comment: @Erix   Yeah you are correct. Got that. So after a little investigation i have found some other queer behavior. I am updating the question with that information

Comment: Why are you getting the key text and comparing the string?  Just use the keyCode constants.

Comment: @AlexBarker yes agreed. But that does not affect the scenario.